# is it ok to create ManyToMany with no through Field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

so in Django models documentation when I have to add extra data to ManytoMany fields, the django documentation recommend I use 'through' like this example

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

in the admin panel this is good but when I try to use it on views.py to create API I get many problems that I can't get Membership fields info from Group model

but when I created model like that it became possible:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

not following docs makes me feel I'm doing it wrong

since I'm a beginner I don't know if the way I did is good or not? like is it bad to create a model like that? if I should go back to using 'through' then is there a possible way to get Membership fields from the Group model?

Comment: Your first snippet creates 3 tables in the database, the second snippet on the other hand creates _4_ tables (Here one of the tables is really redundant). This makes your queries more complicated, potentially increases work for the DB administrator, etc. If your question is "_get Membership fields from the Group model?_" why don't you simply ask _that_? (And give more details for that, it is not really clear what you mean there)

Comment: oh i didn't know it creates more tables without using 'through' thanks for that info, the thing is in my views.py when i write "Group.objects.all()" i only get the id and name for Group fields but i don't get the 'members' field like (person__name, invite_reason , date_joined).

i tried filtering and prefetch_related but i still don't get members result

Comment: `members` will be a related manager that will give related `Person` instances on querying. If you want the `Membership` instances you want to write `group.membership_set.all()` where `membership_set` is the default generated `related_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you'll omit `through` argument for M2M filed, Django will still create a third table to hold relationship between specific `Person` and `Group` records. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#id1) for explanation.

> since I'm a beginner I don't know if the way I did is good or not? like is it bad to create a model like that?

It's not good or bad, but only depends on your requirements. If you don't need extra info for a membership - you can avoid creation of intermediate table (model) by your own and leave it up to Django so that this table will be created behind the scene, but in case you need extra membership fields:

> is there a possible way to get Membership fields from the Group model

, you should create intermediate table with needed fields by yourself

You can also read [this](https://www.sankalpjonna.com/learn-django/the-right-way-to-use-a-manytomanyfield-in-django) article to have a better understanding about M2M usage.